# Javascript inheritance method overriding doesn't work

Tags: javascript, oop

I have trouble understanding how the method overriding works in Javascript.

In the code below, I have **CustomFieldTable** class subclassing from **Table** class, and it both have *createList* function.

How can I override the *createList* function from the below code so that *createList* function from the **CustomFieldTable** class can be run from the *reload* function?

**Current console output:**

```
'Should be silent overridden createList Function'
```

**Desired console output:**

```
'Custom Field create list'
'obj1'
'obj2'
'obj3'
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = new CustomFieldTable();
  table.init();
});


function Table() {
  var self = this;
  self.table_data = [];

  self.reload = function() {
    self.table_data = ["obj1", "obj2", "obj3"];
    self.createList();
  }

  self.createList = function() {
    alert("Should be silent overridden createList Function");
  }
}

CustomFieldTable.prototype = new Table();
CustomFieldTable.prototype.constructor = CustomFieldTable;

function CustomFieldTable() {
  var self = this;

  self.init = function() {
    self.reload();
  }

  self.createList = function() {
    alert("Custom Field create list");

    for (var i = 0; i < self.table_data.length; i++) {
      alert(self.table_data[i]);

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restructure this this way:

```js
function myClass() {
  // Constructor function
  this.myProp = "This is myProp on myClass";
}

myClass.prototype.firstMethod = function() {
  document.write("I am firstMethod on myClass<br\>");
}

myClass.prototype.secondMethod = function() {
  document.write("I am to be overwritten<br\>");
}



function myExtendedClass() {
  // This calls "super" class constructor with the correct "this"
  myClass.call(this);
  this.myOtherProp = "This is a prop only on my extended class<br\>";
}

// Set with super class prototype and set proper constructor
myExtendedClass.prototype = Object.create(myClass.prototype);
myExtendedClass.prototype.contructor = myExtendedClass;

// Overwrite or set new methods on extended class object
myExtendedClass.prototype.secondMethod = function() {
  document.write("I overwrote my super's method<br\>");
}

var a = new myExtendedClass();
console.log(a);
a.firstMethod();
a.secondMethod();
```

To be exact... a correction of your code would be:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = new CustomFieldTable();
  table.init();
});


function Table() {
  this.table_data = [];
}

Table.prototype.reload = function() {
  this.table_data = ["obj1", "obj2", "obj3"];
  this.createList();
}

Table.prototype.createList = function() {
  alert("Should be silent overridden createList Function");
}



function CustomFieldTable() {
  Table.call(this);
}

CustomFieldTable.prototype = Object.create(Table.prototype);
CustomFieldTable.prototype.constructor = CustomFieldTable;


CustomFieldTable.prototype.init = function() {
  this.reload();
}

CustomFieldTable.prototype.createList = function() {
  alert("Custom Field create list");

  for (var i = 0; i < this.table_data.length; i++) {
    alert(this.table_data[i]);

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

A few things to note, when you set these functions inside the constructor you are creating new instances of the function object whenever you create an object.  Instead, use the .prototype to set methods on the object.  Then use Object.create to extend the prototype and call the super from the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is more clear how it works now.